# scr.sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, syntax-error, sh

I'm doing a task, but I got an error: scr.sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")"). When I try to run my schell script on my local computer server, it works, but on the helios ssh server it return an error. Here's my test code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(kitten dog parrot)
for i in ${arr[@]}
do
        echo $i
done
```

I tried to declare array like this:
`arr=("kitten" "dog" "parrot")`, it was the same error.

Using `declare -a arr` didn't work

I run it like this:

```
sh scr.sh
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Helios, but is it possible that your script is being run in a non-Bash shell that doesn't support arrays, or in a very old version of Bash that doesn't support arrays?

Comment: I use GitBash 2.42.0.2. Should I try another shell?

Comment: You need to run it as bash. `sh` does not have arrays. Hence execute it as `bash scr.sh`, or make it executable (`chmod +x scr.sh`) and then run it as `./scr.sh`, in which case your #! line would make sure that _bash_  is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you run the script. You tell it to use `sh` instead of `bash`. Instead do

```bash
bash scr.sh
```

or make the file executable

```
chmod +x scr.sh
```

and then you can run it without manually specifying the scripting language every time:

```
./scr.sh
```